# Insert one-to-many relation using hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

What is the best way to insert data using Hibernate? As a example when I wont to insert new Order into order table. It has one-to-many relationship with Item. when we consider it on Object manner Order object has Item collection. Should I need to populate all variables(itemName,ItemId,ItemSize,, ) in Item object collection ?
If you can please give me the code sample on insert Order using hibernate session..

Comment: The answer depends on your mapping (unidirectional association? bidirectional?) and on what you want to create exactly. What have you tried? What don't you understand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@Entity
@Table(name="orders")
class Order {
@Id @GeneratedId private Long id;
@OneToMany(mappedBy="order")
private List<Item> items;

public Order() {
items = new ArrayList<Item>();
}

public void addItem(Item item) {
if (item != null)
items.add(item);
}
    /* getters setters */
```

}

and item:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="items")
class Item {
@Id @GeneratedId private Long id;
@ManyToOne
private Order order;
/* getters setters */
}
```

to query:

```
Query query = query.createQuery("from Order o where o.id=:id");
query.setLong("id", 1234L);
List<Order> orders = query.list();
```

to insert could like this:

```
Session session = null;

    try {
       session = HibernateUtils.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
       Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();

       Order order = new Order();
       Item item = new Item();
       item.setQuantity(1);
       /* etc.. */
       order.addItem(item);
       item.setOrder(order);
       session.save(item);
       session.save(order);
       tx.commit();
    } finally {
       if (session.isOpen())
           session.close();
    }
```

Comment: why got -1 without any comment?

Comment: "the bidirectional association is mapped twice." - Yes, you're right. It was just a pseudo-like example and didn't try to compile the code.

Comment: @JoinColumn is not necessarily in the item class. Hibernate assumes that there is a {field}_id in your table. in this case order_id field as foreign key must exist in the items table. as i said, it is not a complete code. I think, that the answer doesn't deserve -1 any more.

Comment: Thank you very much your reply ..  
Item 's id  can't be the auto generated one(should not be new Item). Item list should be the existing Items. According to you sample code New Item will be inserted. won't it?

Comment: yeah. we create in the example code a new instance of item and persist it. you could before query an existing item and it could be also associated with a new created order. But @GeneratedId annotation determines the strategy which will be used to manage ids/primary keys, when a new item must be persisted

Comment: That mean, If we need to add 10 item for a Order, I should select those items by query in 10 time and add to OroderList. Is that so?

Comment: it depends. if you can build a query which returns a list of 10 items, you can add all of these in your Collection, which will be persisted later.

Answer (score 0):

Normally you should create your Item object and set the reference to the Order, since in the general case the Item is the owning side of the relation (assuming a birectional association and that you don't want to use a mapping table).

Besides that, can you give more information on what you have already (especially your Order and Item entities) or where exactly your problem is?